# Thymeleaf - how to condition format date value if exists?

Tags: thymeleaf

I have a table that shows dates, but some date values are null or blank. I'd like to format them if they exist and display nothing if there's no value.

I was considering something like:

```
(date != '' ? ${#calendars.format(date,'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm')} : '')
```

Is this possible? How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you have to try something like this?

```
<table>
....
    <td>
        <span th:if="${date != null}" 
              th:text="${#calendars.format(date,'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm')}">
        </span>
    </td>
....
</table>
```

If you have not null value in `date` it will shown another it will be blank table cell.

Comment: It wasn't exactly that, but it gave the way to find out the answer. In my case it was: `<td><span th:if="${date != null}" th:text="${#calendars.format(date,'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm')}"></span></td>`

Answer (score 0):

The shortest way I think is this:

```
<td th:text="${#date} ? ${#calendars.format(date,'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm')}" />
```